# How to restrict IAM Role specific to SQS in aws cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I am new to aws cloudformation template, I want to restrict below role to SQS service only.
Please suggest how can I achieve same using conditional.

My template sample::

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  This template creates Role  
Parameters:
  vpcname:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter vpcname
Resources:
  ErrorQueueRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ["",[ErrorQueueRole.,!Ref vpcname]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - sqs.amazonaws.com
            Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
                StringEquals:
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

SQS uses a [SQS policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-overview-of-managing-access.html) **not an IAM role**, so you would be limited here to the functionality that this provides.

A limited number of services such as SNS, Lambda and S3 support what are commonly known as [resource policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html). Assuming the service (SQS) supports functionality to connect to the service you would need to add the Arn to the service you're trying to trigger.

For example allowing SQS to invoke a Lambda, would require you modify the Lambda function policy such as

```
{
    "Sid": "sqs",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "sqs.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function"
}
```

Comment: Hi. The question is about sqs. Can you explain how sqs can assume a role? I'm curious in what scenario sqs assumes a role?

Comment: Yeah I realised after re reading question after, fixed answer now. Thanks for spotting @Marcin :)

Comment: Thanks. It makes more sense now. Now I can support the answer :-)

Comment: Ideally you want to add Condition keys of `AWS:SourceAccount` and/or `AWS:SourceARN` when you give a resource access to the the service principal otherwise you cant be sure that only your account accesses the Resource. Other accounts may use SPN to access resource.
```
{
    "Sid": "sqs",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "sqs.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
    "Condition": { "StringEquals" :   [ "AWS:SourceAccount": "123456789012" ]   }
}

```